# How to make a line in android that is stretchable, moveable, and rotatable such as this one found in Lucidchart

Tags: android, canvas, imageview, android-view

I'd like to make a line over an ImageView that is editable. Preferably like this one from lucidchart. Is there any Android widget that can accomplish such task?

[image]

Comment: can you share any code that you have?

Answer (score 1):

No. But you can save this line in `png` format with transparency background insert into an `ImageView` and place it over your editable `ImageView`